# Problema com macro que realiza somas dinâmicas e intervalos não continuos

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Tenho uma planilha onde a coluna A possui valores seguintes valores (1,2,4,6,8,10), sendo que os os campos com valor 1 devem ser a soma de todos os grupos 2 abaixo dele até o próximo valor com campo 1, e o grupo 2 deverá ser a soma de todos os valores do grupo 4 abaixo dele até a próxima célula com valor 2, e assim por diante até o grupo 8, que será a soma de todos os valores 10 abaixo dele.

Eu já criei uma estrutura para todos os valores de 8 serem preenchidos, porém os totalizadores de 1 até 6, como não são contínuos, não estou conseguindo somar.

```
For i = 1 To b
    If balancete.Cells(i + 1, 1) = 10 Then
        cont_10 = cont_10 + 1
    ElseIf balancete.Cells(i + 1, 1) <> 10 Then
        If balancete.Cells(i, 1) = 10 Then
           balancete.Cells(i - cont_10, 4) = "=SOMA(D" & i + 1 - cont_10 & ":D" & i & ")"
           cont_10 = 0
        End If
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente somar os valores na medida com que você os conta.

```
Dim soma As Double
soma = 0

For i = 1 To b
    If balancete.Cells(i + 1, 1) = 10 Then

        cont_10 = cont_10 + 1
        soma = soma + balancete.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value 'soma os valores a medida com que são localizados

    ElseIf balancete.Cells(i + 1, 1) <> 10 Then
        If balancete.Cells(i, 1) = 10 Then
           balancete.Cells(i - cont_10, 4) = soma 'preenche a celular com o valor total
           cont_10 = 0
        End If
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Felipe, como a base de dados possui diversas colunas, eu pensei em deixar a célula preenchida como fórmula, para que fosse fácil replicar para as demais colunas da tabela, da forma que você mencionou eu teria que replicar o preenchimento ara muitas colunas, o que levaria muito tempo.

A fórmula acima preenche as células com uma fórmula de soma, após isso a minha macro copia a mesma fórmula e arrasta para as demais colunas.

Answer (score -1):

Muito obrigado Felipe, como a base de dados possui diversas colunas, eu pensei em deixar a célula preenchida como fórmula, para que fosse fácil replicar para as demais colunas da tabela, da forma que você mencionou eu teria que replicar o preenchimento ara muitas colunas, o que levaria muito tempo.

```
Dim soma As Double
soma = 0

For i = 1 To b
If balancete.Cells(i + 1, 1) = 10 Then

    cont_10 = cont_10 + 1
    soma = soma + balancete.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value 'soma os valores a medida com que são localizados

ElseIf balancete.Cells(i + 1, 1) <> 10 Then
    If balancete.Cells(i, 1) = 10 Then
       balancete.Cells(i - cont_10, 4) = soma 'preenche a celular com o valor total
       cont_10 = 0
    End If
Else
    i = i + 1
End If
Next i
```

A fórmula acima preenche as células com uma fórmula de soma, após isso a minha macro copia a mesma fórmula e arrasta para as demais colunas.

Comment: Para agradecer ao colega, marque a resposta dele como "resposta" e se foi muito útil clique na seta para cima!! Sugiro apagar esta resposta e se for o caso fazer um comentário na resposta dele o que alterou, pois parece que sua resposta ficou igual à do colega.